# Array Keys Comparison Without In-Build Function

Tags: php

I am having two arrays of **key-value** pairs.
Arrays as follows:

```
$array1 = ["a" => 2, "b" => 3, "c" => 1, "d" => 2];
$array2 = ["c" => 1, "d" => 1, "a" => 2, "b" => 3, "x" => 4, "z" => 1];
```

**Problem Statement**
I need to find the `count` of the number of `keys` of `array1` present in `array2` having the same `value`.
**Example**
`Count` will be **3** as `keys` **a**, **b**, and **c** of `array1` are present in `array2` and having same values **2**, **3**, and **1** respectivily.
Tried method

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){ 
    if($array2.$key === $array1.$key){
       if($array2[$value] === $array1[$value]){
          $matchCount++;
       }
    }
}
```

> NOTE: I am not sure about accessing the keys from the array object, so using dot(.), somehow I am getting the count, but not correct count.

Comment: Why can't you use an in-built function, that's what they're there for.

Comment: you use square brackets to access array key. Instead of `$array2.$key`, you do `$array2[$key]`

Comment: Okay, can you tell how to do that using built-in functions?

Comment: `$array1` and `$array2` are not valid PHP structures. Are they supposed to be arrays with associative keys?

Comment: @Nick Yes, arrays with associative keys. But for keeping it simple, I wrote that example. I know it should  be  ```Array( [a]=> 2   [b] => 1)``` similarly to like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$array1 = ["a" => 2, "b" => 3, "c" => 1, "d" => 2];
$array2 = ["c" => 1, "d" => 1, "a" => 2, "b" => 3, "x" => 4, "z" => 1];

$count = 0;

foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    $array_2_value = $array2[$key] ?? null;
    if($array_2_value !== null && $array_2_value === $value) $count++;
}

echo $count;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/BREbg

You can just loop over `$array1` and check if the key exists in `$array2` with the same value. If yes, we increment count. You can make use of [`null coalescing operator ??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) to check if the `$key` exists in `$array2` or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
function countSameKeyAndValues(array $array1, array $array2): int 
{
    $sameKeys = array_keys(array_intersect($array1, $array2));
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($sameKeys as $key) {
        if ($array1[$key] === $array2[$key]) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Without using built in function. At least avoid `array_intersect`

Comment: I am actually looking without any build-in function, anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the **$array1** using `foreach` loop.

Then you can check for the values of **$array2** using the `key` for `$array1`.

Then if value exist for that key, you can check if value is same at that of `$array1`

```
<?php

   $array1 = ["a" => 2, "b" => 3, "c" => 1, "d" => 2];
   $array2 = ["c" => 1, "d" => 1, "a" => 2, "b" => 3, "x" => 4, "z" => 1];

   $count = 0;

   foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
      $array2Value = $array2[$key] ?? null;
      if($array2Value !== null && $array2Value === $value) 
        $count++;
   }

echo $count;
```